# Data base update query exception handling error

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

```
String Query="insert into sms (Jobno, Mobilenumber, MStatus, ReceivedTime, AmountDeducted, Message, DoneTime)       values ("+jobnum +","+mobilenum+","+ smsstatus+",'"+ rxtimestamp+ "',"+ amt+",'"+smstxt+"','"+timedone1+"')";
```

Note: Through the Mysql the above query is executed successfully....

I imported all the required libraries and their respective interfaces in the program....
When i execute through java panel/ide its throwing the following errors?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'Mobilenumber' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
```

Please suggest what could be the problem...........

Comment: it looks like a datatype or datatype length issue. what are you passing through code? the error means the value you are passing exceeds the allowed length of `mobile number` in database

Comment: Don't just concatenate strings to construct your query, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: Goel: you are right... i used int rather bigint for mobile number... Any how i changed the data type now problem solved..... Thank you

Comment: @KarthikKolla , you are welcome. a suggestion please use `@` to tag people on SO , so they are notified you are referring to them in some comments. here it was fine but this may have caused you indefinite waiting in case you have asked for more clarification as the person will not be notified and rarely people come and check on there posts.  
if you plan to be active on SO, you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of value from the variable mobileNumber is more than its limit. So check the datatype you have defined in both DB and java program and verify the mobileNumber you have given to save.

Comment: Thank you.... I changed the data type from int to bigint in my DB .... Now problem got solved

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the type, range and length of the column 'Mobilenumber' and furthermore put the inserted values into '' to avoid issues with spaces, other characters in the inserted mobilenumber (e.g. "+" or "/") and long mobile numbers. If it's a real number, MySQL should correctly convert the text into a number transparently.

i.e. the resulting code should be:

```
String Query="insert into sms (Jobno, Mobilenumber, MStatus, ReceivedTime, AmountDeducted, Message, DoneTime)       values ('"+jobnum +"','"+mobilenum+"','"+ smsstatus+"','"+ rxtimestamp+ "','"+ amt+"','"+smstxt+"','"+timedone1+"')";
```

One additional hint: always try to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to avoid opening possibilities for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you.... I changed the data type from int to bigint in my DB .... Now problem got solved